# Log4j configuration for multiple loggers

Tags: log4j

I have a single log4j.properties file in the server and to applications deployed in the server.The requirement is to create separate loggers for the application
I defined this in my application

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/opt/ibm/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/MDMServer/logs/damcoLoging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

   #logging for jbpm
log4j.logger.jbpmLogger=INFO, jbpmLogger
log4j.appender.jbpmLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.jbpmLogger.maxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.jbpmLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.jbpmLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.jbpmLogger.File=/opt/ibm/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/MDMServer/logs/jbpmLogging.log
log4j.additivity.jbpmLogger=false
```

In my java class I have done this for the secondary logger

```
 Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("jbpmLogger");
```

Now the logs are getting generated properly.But for the secondary logger I want to set the class name as well.So that I can know from which class the log is generating.
Currently the log for the secondary logger looks like this

```
INFO  jbpmLogger:8 - Hi
```

Is it possible to set the class name as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class name to the output [Pattern](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) with %C, although the docs warn that this is slow. Is this what you want?

Or since one`getLogger()` method takes a String, you could concatenate the class and your "jbpmLogger" if you wanted to. And since the naming is hierarchical, still just using your single logger in the configuration file. e.g.

```
Logger logger = getLogger("jbpmLogger." + this.getClass().getName());
```